# generating a set of javascript code using php

Tags: php

I´m trying using php to generate a set of "{URL.callback}" to use in javascript. By using database. Here is my code:

```
$sql="select * from search where keywords LIKE '$bb%' ORDER BY keywords ";  

     $result=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql);

     echo $_GET["callback"] . "({ t:\"$t\", r:[";
    while ( $rs=mysql_fetch_array($result))    {
        $keywords=$rs[keywords];

         echo "" ."\"$keywords\"".","." ";
    }

echo"] })";
```

This is the code it returns:

```
({ t:"", r:["example1", "example2", "example3",] })
```

Everything seemed to be correct except the (,) in the end (after "example3") that I want to get rid. because it´s not correct and can not be use with that.

The question is: How to generate it correctly ? How to get rid the last (,) ?

Comment: I got the solution from "refp"...Now I´m very happy :)))

Comment: I also got the good solution from "Indranil", "Billy Moon"  Thank you so much for help.

Comment: If you got the solution from @refp, then mark his answer as accepted (that little tick under vote count for his answer) :)

Comment: "Shoogle" is also give me the solution. Thank you again..

Comment: Ahh now I know how to mark the answer that was correct. But every answers here are correct...So sad I can mark only one time :S BUt anyway want to say thank you for everybody !

Comment: I also got the last solution from "Tadeck" that also work for me :)
Thank you for everybody here...Now I can sleep without stress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Create data structure (multi-dimensional array) within PHP and let `json_encode()` generate JS data structure.

### Example

It could look like this:

```
$sql="select * from search where keywords LIKE '$bb%' ORDER BY keywords ";  
$result=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql);

$data = array(
    't' => $t,
    'r' => array(),
);

while ( $rs=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data['r'][] = $rs['keywords'];
};
```

and then display it like that:

```
echo $_GET["callback"].'('.json_encode($data).');';
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I actually got the solution from "refp" But I will try yours also wait....

Comment: @AleksanderPaitoon: You are welcome. I suggest you should follow his original solution to use `json_encode()` instead of manually creating JS representation of your data. It will do the job better and simplify your code at the same time.

Comment: Hi although I got the solution already but I want to say thank you that you also help me. I appreciate it. I also tried your code. Seemed like the (,) is gone. But I got the strange encode like this "u0e2b\u0e32\u0e04\u0e21 2553"

Maybe I don´t know what to do more...I want to say thank you again :)

Comment: @AleksanderPaitoon: This is probably because there were some specials characters inside keywords. You can test how it works eg. here: [codepad.org/LQQVQHjw](http://codepad.org/LQQVQHjw).

Comment: Thanks Tadeck...Your answer is also give me the solution. I will post at the end of my question that you gave me the solution also :)

Sorry that I was stupid but after I test it...worked fine...

Comment: @AleksanderPaitoon: No problem, I am glad it helped :) You do not need to post names of people who helped you - this is usually done by upvoting answers, adding comments to the answers and eventually - for the best answer - by marking it as accepted one.

Comment: I found that your answer really help me...Even all other answer give me the correct php set, but it made my autocomplete not work propely. The problem is when I type keyword that not match anything in database anymore, the autocomplete would not disappear as it should. But finally I found it worked after I use your php script...Cheers !

Comment: @Alex There is no difference between this answer and my more elaborate one, could you shed some light on why the above helped you more? This is because of two reasons; 1. I'm curious 2. maybe I can keep something in mind til' next time I answer questions

Comment: The reason is when I use yours the autoomplete would not work properly. WHen I type wrong message it would not disappear as it should. I use whole week to find out in the javascript and everything. But finally I started to change the php to each of ther answer here..I got surprise that the autocomplete work 100 % perfect without any problem...It made me so happy.But as i said that every question here is correct, because my question was to generate the correct php. But this script worked best for me because all problem is gone. And tha is what I want.

Comment: And if you want me to guess I would guess that because something call ('.json_encode($data).'); 

Because the data that send back to javascript was not encoded and that why it not work properly..

Comment: @refp: there are some minor problems with your solution. First of all, it does not do what OP wanted it to do. It does not output function call, only a JS data structure enclosed in brackets. Second, it shows multiple solutions, some of which could be PITA for future developers. Generally it is a good idea to use the simplest solution possible, especially the one designed specifically to fulfill given task. In this case it was using `json_encode`. And the most important difference: my answer solved the problem without creating additional ones.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of generating the JSON yourself use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to do the heavy lifting for you.

```
$keywords = array ();

while ( $rs=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $keywords[] = $rs['keywords'];
}

echo json_encode ($keywords);
```

**Preferred solution**

Though if you plan on using `json_encode` append $keywords to your other set of data and use `json_encode` on the whole structure.

```
$json_data = array (
  't' => '',
  'r' => array ()
);

while ( $rs=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $json_data['r'][] = $rs['keywords'];
}

echo "(".json_encode ($json_data).")";
```

---

If you'd like to do it yourself there are a few (rather clean) options available, see the snippets below.

---

Append all retrieved keywords to an array and use [`join`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) with ',' as delimiter to form a string after your while loop
 
    $keyword_array = array ();

```
while ($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result))    {   
  $keywords=$rs[keywords];

  $keyword_array = "\"$keywords\"";
}

echo join (', ', $keywords);
```

---

Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) before your while loop to get the number of rows in `$result`, and don't append a `,` when you are processing the last element.

```
$n_rows = mysql_num_rows ($result);

for ($i =1; $rs = mysql_fetch_array ($result); ++$i) {
  $keywords=$rs[keywords];

  echo "\"$keywords\"";

  if ($i != $n_rows)
    echo ", ";
}
```

Comment: OHHHHHHHH MMMMMMMMYYYY GODDDDD  I got it :)    THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: @AleksanderPaitoon Please make sure to flag the post as accepted as that will mark your question as solved, and make me tremendously happy ;)

Comment: I´m very new here. I´ve tried to post at the end of my question above that I got the solution from you :))) And I clicked on flag and post that I got the solution from you refp. :))) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$output = '';
while ( $rs=mysql_fetch_array($result))    {
    $keywords=$rs[keywords];

     $output .= "" ."\"$keywords\"".","." ";
}
$output = substr($output, 0, -2);
echo $output;
```

Comment: to Indranil 
Thanks for help, but i still get the (,) in the end.

Comment: Your answer is also give the solution, I will post for you in the end of my question...Thank you so much for this

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

```
$sql="select * from search where keywords LIKE '$bb%' ORDER BY keywords ";  

 $result=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql);

 echo $_GET["callback"] . "({ t:\"$t\", r:[";
$keywords_print = array();
while ( $rs=mysql_fetch_array($result))    {
    $keywords=$rs[keywords];

     $keywords_print[] = "\"$keywords\"";
}
echo implode(",",$keywords_print);
echo"] })";
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I actually got the solution from "refp" But I will try yours also wait....

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your answer. It also give me the solution... I will post at the end of my question tat you also help me find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way, is to create an array of elements, then implode them with a `,` as separator.

```
// added initial `"`
echo $_GET["callback"] . "({ t:\"$t\", r:[\"";
while ( $rs=mysql_fetch_array($result))    {
    $keywords=$rs[keywords];
    $arr[] = $keywords;
}
echo implode('", "', $arr);
// added closing `"`
echo "\"] })";
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I actually got the solution from "refp" But I will try yours also wait....

Comment: I will, with baited breath :)

Comment: I can tell you without executing the above that it sadly will not work, you are appending each `$keywords` to `$arr` but then using `$keywords` when you `implode`, probably a little bit of typo thingie!

Comment: Hi, Billy moon...I found that your answer is also give the solution for me...I will post at the end of my question that you also give the good solution for me.